# Which city is the one being searched for the virologist?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

Question in spoiler tags below

> In July, searches are introduced. The *Search for the Virologist* indicates that if there is a quarantine marker in the city you are searching, advance the search party one additional space. Elsewhere on the card, though, when instructing how many spaces to advance, it refers to "your city". Is the city you are in the one you are searching, or is the city on the card you discarded the one you are searching?

The actual text of the card can be seen in [this image](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20687079#20687079)

Relevant text copied below as well

> Take the search action if you are in a faded city with a research station
>  Advance 1 space for each card you discard matching the color of your city
>  If there is a quarantine marker in the city you are searching, advance the search party 1 additional space per search action.

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, I don't see how you could entertain the second interpretation at all! From this picture: https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20687079#20687079

> ADVANCE 3 SPACES IF YOU DISCARD THE CARD MATCHING YOUR CITY

There is clearly a distinction between the [city listed on the] discarded card and the city where the active player's pawn is located. Furthermore, since you are able to discard multiple cards, it doesn't make any sense that the cities on those cards would be "yours".

"Your city" is the city where you are.

Comment: I think your answer is technically spot on, but could be improved by the removal of the first sentence which doesn't seem either necessary or particularly nice. (Then I will delete this comment and upvote.)

Comment: Yes, "your city" is clearly the city in which your pawn is located. But, the bit about the quarantine marker uses the term "the city you are searching", not "your city". Surely, if the first interpretation were correct, the wording would have been "If there is a quarantine marker in your city, advance 1 extra...", since the term "your city" is used elsewhere on the card to indicate that exact thing?

Comment: Further, the wording for advancing 1 space is "Advance 1 space for each card you discard matching the color of your city"; this makes multiple discards make sense. There is only 1 card matching "your city", but there are many matching the color of "your city"